# indexPathsForVisibleRows contains incorrect row count

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

I've got a viewController with a tableView. On a 6s Plus, 5 rows are visible without any scrolling. If I tap a row and navigate to the next viewController, when I come back to my tableView, it's `indexPathsForVisibleRows` is wrong.

Here's the test code I have set up:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ...
    NSLog(@"will appear: %@", self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows);
}

- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    ...
    NSLog(@"did appear: %@", self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows);
}
```

When I first enter the viewController with the tableView, I get this:

```
will appear: (null)
did appear: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}"
)
```

After tapping a row and then coming back to the viewController with the tableView, I get this:

```
will appear: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000a00016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 5}"  <----THIS IS MY PROBLEM
)
did appear: (
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000000016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 0}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000200016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 1}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000400016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 2}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000600016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 3}",
    "<NSIndexPath: 0xc000000000800016> {length = 2, path = 0 - 4}"
)
```

Why is `indexPathsForVisibleRows` reporting an extra visible row in `viewWillAppear` after navigating back?

Comment: The method `indexPathsForVisibleRows` returns the number of cells the table view believes is visible.  Even if only one row of pixels is visible.  Also, it may be clipped, but if it's within the content area, the table view will count it.  The more important question is, other than intellectual curiosity, why care?